# How to sync two animations using css keyframes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on solution

I have created a basic html banner where I want to keep image and text animations in sync.

Basically image animation is like scale logo for about 3 seconds, meanwhile logo is animated I want text for same in typing effect

I have created basic solution using css and javascript but it is not in sync

```js
var typewriter = function(txt) {
  var container = document.getElementById('typewriter'),
    speed = 28,
    i = 0,
    wordsObj = txt.split(" ")
  container.textContent = "";
  runAllWords();

  function runAllWords() {

    if (i < wordsObj.length) {
      var a = (i == 0) ? i : i - 1;
      setTimeout(function() {
        showWord(wordsObj[i], 0)
      }, wordsObj[a].length * speed);
    }
  }

  function showWord(word, countWord) {
    if (countWord < word.length) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        showLetter(word, countWord)
      }, speed);
    } else {
      container.textContent = container.textContent + " ";
      i += 1;
      runAllWords();
    }
    if (i === wordsObj.length) {
      console.log('complete')
    }
  }

  function showLetter(word, countWord) {
    container.textContent = container.textContent + word[countWord];
    showWord(word, countWord + 1);
  }
}

var i = 0;

function myLoop() {
  //  create a loop function

  var dataType = document.getElementById('typewriter').dataset.typewriter,
    w = dataType.split(',')
  setTimeout(function() { //  call a 3s setTimeout when the loop is called
    typewriter(w[i]); //  your code here
    i++; //  increment the counter
    if (i < w.length) { //  if the counter < 10, call the loop function
      myLoop(); //  ..  again which will trigger another 
    } //  ..  setTimeout()
  }, 3000)
}

myLoop();
```

```css
.addsp_320x50 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.addsp_320x50_img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 0px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.addsp_title_text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 70px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.addsp_title_desc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 70px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  color: #999;
}

.addsp_320x50_action button {
  height: 27px;
  background: #058562;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #058562;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.adz_text_1 {}

.adz_text_2 {
  animation: text2;
}

.adz_text_1,
.adz_text_2 {}

@keyframes text2 {
  0%,
  50%,
  100% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  60%,
  90% {
    width: 200px;
  }
}

@keyframes text1 {
  0%,
  50%,
  100% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  10%,
  40% {
    width: 200px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .addsp_320x50_img {
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    top: 4px;
    left: 5px;
  }
  .addsp_title_text {
    top: 14px;
    left: 56px;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
  }
  .addsp_title_desc {
    top: 25px;
    left: 55px;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .addsp_title_text {
    top: 3px;
    left: 55px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }
  .addsp_title_desc {
    top: 28px;
    left: 55px;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .addsp_title_text {
    top: 3px;
    left: 70px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }
  .addsp_title_desc {
    top: 28px;
    left: 70px;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .addsp_title_text {
    top: 3px;
    left: 70px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }
  .addsp_title_desc {
    top: 28px;
    left: 70px;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
}

.addsp_320x50_img:nth-child(1) {
  animation-name: scale;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

.addsp_320x50_img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-name: scale;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

.addsp_320x50_img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-name: scale;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 7s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: 1
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: 1
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1
  }
  90% {
    transform: translateY(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.blinking-cursor {
  color: #2E3D48;
  -webkit-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  -moz-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  -ms-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  -o-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes "blink" {
  from,
  to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
  from,
  to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes "blink" {
  from,
  to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes "blink" {
  from,
  to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes "blink" {
  from,
  to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="addsp_320x50">
  <img src="https://de7yjjf51n4cm.cloudfront.net/banners/amazonprime_newicon.jpg" class="addsp_320x50_img">
  <img src="https://de7yjjf51n4cm.cloudfront.net/banners/amazonprime_newicon.jpg" class="addsp_320x50_img">
  <img src="https://de7yjjf51n4cm.cloudfront.net/banners/amazonprime_newicon.jpg" class="addsp_320x50_img">
  <div class="addsp_title_text">
    <span class="adz_text_1 typewriter" id="typewriter" data-typewriter="Web Strategy,
      UX Testing,
      Content Management System,
      Web Design,
      Research and Analytics,
      Information Architecture,
      Strategic Consulting,Maintenance and Support"></span><span class="blinking-cursor">|</span>
  </div>
  <div class="addsp_320x50_action">
    <button>DOWNLOAD</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem with this is that you cannot know when javascript is going to execute, the animation of the logo is being done with `css` why not do both of them with `javascript` that way you have control over what is happening

Comment: Your question is vague. I suggest you reclarify what you want. Is this what you want: 1. Make the image scale up and down while the text is being typed (total animation time is 3s regardless of text length), 2. When the text finishes typing, the image goes up, 3. Text becomes an empty string and image suddenly appears scaling up and down again?

Comment: i have a function that perfectly animates `element properties` and `elements styles` Synchronously , however it won't help you animate typing  , i would suggest you to search and read about `lerp method` and `window.requestAnimationFrame()` to get the idea , you should assign a percentage of entire progress at each moment of time , together , lerp gives you the value for each moment of time , take a look at my  [style animator](https://jsfiddle.net/BrightFaith/9rn1jhyt/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the [animation iteration event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationiteration_event) and the [animation start event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationstart_event).

Instead of just using the myLoop function to call itself, try using these listeners to call it instead.

The end of your js file would look like:

```
var i = 0;

function myLoop() {
  var dataType = document.getElementById("typewriter").dataset.typewriter,
    w = dataType.split(",");

  if (i < w.length -1 ) {
    typewriter(w[i]);
  }

  i++;
}

var imageElems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.addsp_320x50_img'));
imageElems.forEach(elem=>{
 elem.addEventListener('animationstart',myLoop);
});
```

Where ".addsp_320x50_img" is just whatever common selector you give to all the images.

Comment: Yes image urls are same but i will render different images that will be totally dynamic based on json response i get 
i just posted question for my confusion

Comment: I want to sync image transition with typing effect whenever image transition occurs related text will appear both will be array

Comment: @JanakPrajapati , will both the array be in the correct order and of the same size? If so, check my editted answer and let me know what you think

Comment: Yes both images and text array will have same size

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically speaking, sinking means adjusting frequency and phase. I'll demonstrate each separately. Note that what I'm gonna explain is the concept and you can implement it in your codes using Javascript, css, etc

### Frequency

> You can't sink two animations unless the longer duration is a factor
>   of shorter duration.

For example in your codes, blinking has a duration of 1s. So your image *scaling duration* and Also *the whole duration* must be a selection of either 1s, 2s, 3s, ... or 1/2s, 1/3s, ...

For better understanding let me make a simple example. Assume two images want to be animated.

```
<img src="1.png" id="img1">
<img src="1.png" style="margin-left: 50px;" id="img2">
```

Consider two different animations for each one

```
@keyframes k1
{
    25%
    {
        transform: rotate(-4deg);
    }
    50%
    {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    75%
    {
        transform: rotate(3deg);
    }
    100%
    {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}

@keyframes k2
{
    50%
    {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    100%
    {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

So since k2 is simpler, I'll first assign it to img2 with duration of 0.7s

```
#img2
{
    animation: k2 0.7s linear infinite;
}
```

And based on what was explained, I will assign animation k1 to img1 with a duration of 1.4s. (NOT 1.3s NOT 1.5s **VERY IMPORTANT!**)

```
#img1
{
    animation: k1 1.4s linear infinite;
}
```

If you run this code you'll see they are sink! To feel the concept better, change the duration of k1 to 0.9s. Now it feels like they are doing their thing separately! 
***Note***
I set k1 to 1.4s (0.7s × 2) because k1 seems to be a combination of one go forward and come back and using 2x feels they are dancing together with the same harmony!

### Phase

In css, phase is showed by `animation-delay`. Modifying frequencies (duration) is enough to sink two animations but if two animation begin at the same time it will feel better! So to illustrate set a delay for img1 of 0.2s. They are still sink but it doesn't feel nice! Now change the delay to 0.7s. Now it's beautiful again! (Maybe even more beautiful)
[image]

### Back to your code

Your images scale with duration of 1.2s (40% of 3s) and your text blinking duration is 1s and as you can see they are not factor of each other so you can't sink!

Comment: What if the user is in a slow 3g network and the image takes 0.4s seconds longer to load than the text and javascript? The css animation will start with the network delay, while the javascript will start animating the text before the image has even been added to the screen. Although your solution is mathematically correct, it is not guaranteed to work in his code. An active synchronization solution is needed.

Comment: Good question! You can add an event listener for images and initiate animations after all images are loaded (for example put animation information in a class and after everything is loaded add that class to images) Or I used this trick in one of my projects that you can design another keyframe to take your style to its first position in a nice way. Then when other images are loaded as well, initiate whole animations. @PedroPessoa

Answer (score 1):

If you control the animation with the same JavaScript loop as the typewriter script, it won't lose sync. I rewrote the typewriter script to do this in the snippet below.

#### `startTypewriter()` Exaplaination

First, all the messages from the are collected converted into an array.

```
typewriter.getAttribute('data-typewriter').split(',');
```

Then the CSS icon animation is started. Because JavaScript intervals wait for their duration before executing their code, so the first message is typed by calling `type()` before the interval is created.

```
icon.classList.add('icon-animation');

type(typewriter, messages[0].trim(), animationDuration - pauseDuration);
```

The interval is now started, running every 3 seconds by default. The first thing that happens is the animation is reset in case it got out of sync somehow.

```
icon.classList.remove('icon-animation');
window.setTimeout(function() {
  icon.classList.add('icon-animation');
}, 25);
```

Next, the message is typed by calling `type()`. Before it ends, a check is run so see if it's on the last array element. If so, it will start over.

```
if (i == messages.length) i = 0;
```

#### `type()` Exaplaination

At the start, the `timePerCharacter` value is calculated. The message is split to an array and the typewriter output is cleared

```
var timePerCharacter = duration / message.length;
var message = message.split('');
typewriter.innerHTML = '';
```

A loop is created, running every `timePerCharacter`. The character is outputted to the typewriter output.

```
typewriter.innerHTML += message[i];
```

Once all the characters are outputted, the loop is cleared

```
if (i == message.length) clearInterval(typeLoop);
```

#### Snippent

```js
var animationDuration = 3000;
var pauseDuration = 2000;

startTypewriter();

function startTypewriter() {
  var typewriter = document.getElementById('typewriter');
  var icon = document.getElementById('icon');
  var messages = typewriter.getAttribute('data-typewriter').split(',');
  
  icon.classList.add('icon-animation');
  
  type(typewriter, messages[0].trim(), animationDuration - pauseDuration);
    
  var i = 1;
  
  window.setInterval(function() {
    icon.classList.remove('icon-animation');
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      icon.classList.add('icon-animation');
    }, 25);
    
    type(typewriter, messages[i].trim(), animationDuration - pauseDuration);
    
    i++;
    
    if (i == messages.length) i = 0;
  }, animationDuration);
}

function type(typewriter, message, duration) {
  var timePerCharacter = duration / message.length;
  var message = message.split('');
  typewriter.innerHTML = '';

  var i = 0;

  var typeLoop = window.setInterval(function() {  
    typewriter.innerHTML += message[i];
    
    i++;
  
    if (i == message.length) clearInterval(typeLoop);
  }, timePerCharacter);
}
```

```css
@keyframes icon {
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  
  40% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  
  80% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-200%);
  }
}

.icon {
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.icon-animation {
  animation: icon 3s;
}

@keyframes cursor {
  50% {
    color: transparent;
  }
}

.blinking-cursor {
  animation: cursor 1s steps(1) infinite;
}
```

```html
<img id="icon" src="https://de7yjjf51n4cm.cloudfront.net/banners/amazonprime_newicon.jpg" class="icon">

<span id="typewriter" data-typewriter="
        Web Strategy,
      UX Testing,
      Content Management System,
      Web Design,
      Research and Analytics,
      Information Architecture,
      Strategic Consulting,
        Maintenance and Support
">
</span>
<span class="blinking-cursor">|</span>
```